# how to use list comprehension to subset the dataframe with the valuecounts

Tags: pandas

```
make     year
honda    2011
honda    2011
honda    n/a
toyota   2011
toyota   2022
```

Im trying to get list of the make that has value counts more than 2 below is code:

```py
list = [I for I in df.make.unique() if df.loc[df.make==I, 'make'].value_counts()>2]
```

for some reason I get following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vc = df['make'].value_counts()
vc[vc>2].index.to_list()
```

o/p:

```
['honda']
```

as for your error:

```
[I for I in df.make.unique() if (df.loc[df.make==I, 'make'].value_counts()>2).values[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`count` is enough

```py
lst = [I for I in df.make.unique() if df.loc[df.make==I, 'make'].count()>2]
```

You can also use

```py
lst = df.value_counts('make')[df.value_counts('make')>2].index.tolist()
```

```
print(lst)
['honda']
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another way to do it

```
df = data.groupby("make")['make'].count().to_frame(name='cnt').reset_index()
df[df.cnt > 2]['make'].to_list()
```

returning a list

```
['honda']
```